# Return class from enum variable

Tags: java

```
    public Object selectClass(Enumvar var){
    switch(var){
    case SOMETHING:
         return new OneClass();
    case SOMETHINGELSE:
         return new AnotherClass();

    return null;
    }
```

so then i would call something like

```
selectClass(SOMETHING).Somefunction();
```

Is it possible something like this?

Comment: Yes. You can easily try that on your own. Using `Object` as return type will limit your possibilities for methods to call, you will probably have to introduce some interface or super class for all the possible returned class isntances

Comment: If `.SomeFunction()` were on the `Object` class. You might wish return an Interface that the various classes implement. You could obtain the class and cast. However, in essence you are implementing a type of Factory, so I would suggest implementing a Factory system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to introduce an interface/class that declares that method and have all classes return implement/extend that.

```
public interface Something {
    void Somefunction();
}

public Something selectClass(Enumvar var){
   switch(var){
   case SOMETHING:
     return new OneClass();
   // ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, another way to do this:

```
public interface Instance {
    void Somefunction();
}

public interface InstanceClass {
    public Instance create();
}

public enum Enumvar implements InstanceClass {
    SOMETHING {
        public Instance create() { return new OneClass(); }
    },
    SOMETHINGELSE {
        public Instance create() { return new AnotherClass(); }
    };
}
```

You can now write:

```
SOMETHING.create().SomeFunction();
```

or:

```
SOMETHINGELSE.create().SomeFunction();
```